# Basic Button Problems in C#

Tags: c#, button, backup

and thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm using Visual Studio to create a program that will store several flash drive backup profiles to buttons in a C# GUI using Visual Studio 2017. Thing is, I'm getting some errors I can't figure out, mostly due to this being my first time working in C# and some code hiding on the part of Microsoft.

-The first error involves Controls.Add not showing up for a button, even though every online source tells me this is how to add a button at Line 78 of Main Window.

-The second involves my not knowing how to give a button a method of another class at Line 76 of Main Window.

The code:
**Profile.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
public class Profile
{
    private string mySource, myDestination, myName;
    public Profile()
    {
        myName = myDestination = mySource = "";
    }
    public Profile(string name, string source, string destination)
    {
        myName = name;
        mySource = source;
        myDestination = destination;
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WpfApp1\profiles.txt"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(myName);
            file.WriteLine(mySource);
            file.WriteLine(myDestination);
            file.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
    public void backup()
    {
        try
        {
            FileSystem.CopyDirectory(mySource, myDestination,
    UIOption.AllDialogs);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return myName;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            refresh();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the profile: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the folder which you want to copy (ENTER EXACTLY AS IN FILE SYSTEM): ");
            string source = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter backup destination (ENTER EXACTLY AS IN FILE SYSTEM): ");
            string destination = Console.ReadLine();
            refresh();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the EXACT name of the profile you want to delete: ");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();

                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WpfApp1\profiles.txt");
                for (int i = 0; lines[i] != null; i += 1)
            {
                if (lines[i] == line)
                {
                    lines[i] = lines[i + 1] = lines[i + 2] = "";
                    i += 2;
                }
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WpfApp1\profiles.txt", lines);

        }
        private void ButtonBackup(Profile pro)
        {
            pro.backup();
        }
        public void refresh()
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\WpfApp1\profiles.txt");
            String reader = "placeholder";
            int i = 0;
            while (reader != null)
            {
                reader = lines[i];
                i += 1;
                if (reader != "\n")
                {
                    String name = reader;
                    reader = lines[i];
                    i += 1;
                    String source = reader;
                    reader = lines[i];
                    String destination = reader;
                    i++;
                    Profile newprofile = new Profile(name, source, destination);
                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.Name = name;
                    b.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonBackup(newprofile); //error 1
                    System.Windows.Controls.Add(b); //error 2
                }

            }
        }





    }

    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: The whole text of your question is a bitt messing. The header and all concerning the target of your app (backup..) has nothing to do with the question which basically reads for me "How to write an WPF application in C# for absolute beginners".

Comment: Do you expect people to count the line numbers in your code given above to find line 76 and 78?

Comment: Yeah, probably bad wording on my part...what I meant to express is that I can't see the code that makes the first two buttons ("add profile" and "delete profile"), so I don't have an example to work from.

Comment: Next time please publish only the lines which correspond to the issue (here the buttons), and not so much unrelated stuff (file management).

Comment: Added comments to show where errors are.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, you have just created the WPF application in the right way?
(File / New / Project .. Templates / Windows Classic Desktop ..)

Click there finally on **WPF app** and everything is correctly configured to work with WPF, especially with buttons ;-)

Please just create a new project like this and create button there before anything else.

You seem to have started without knowing much about WPF, so reading or watching something about it with some examples, could be useful.

If the project is fresh, most easy thing is to go to the file **MainWindow.xaml** , switch to the **Toolbox** on the very very left side, and drag a button to the windows. (If 'Toolbox' is not there, add it with View / Toolbox) by menu.)

Xaml Code will contain something like this:

```
> <Grid>
>         <Button>
>             <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
>         </Button>
> </Grid>
```

Then doubleclick on the button in the designer view (not on the xml code :-) and Visual Studio will automatically create the button event handler function for you and put your cursor there:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

In your MainWindow.xaml.cs file, you will find many using statements, esp. the `using System.Windows.Controls;` but you can delete them with right mouse click and "Remove and sort usings".

Following to this point you have proved yourself that you don't need System.Windows.Controls to work with simple controls like "Button" which are on the toolbox available!

Comment: Just added everything to a new project, but it's giving the same errors. Would you happen to know if declaring both "System.Windows" and "System.Windows.Controls" interferes with the "System.Windows.Controls.Add(b)" call, or how to give a function call to a button that requires additional arguments? I think that's where the problems lie.

Comment: Please read newly added answer again. Just create a new project without adding anything (What you mean with "everything" in your sentence 'Just added everything'). You can create a new button very easily as described without NOTHING else needed. Especially you don't need System.Windows.Controls. Why you want to use an Add function from there???

Comment: OK, when you HAVE already buttons and you are searching for the code-behind file, you can right click on the MainWindows.xaml file and either choose "View Code" or "View designer"

Comment: Now I understood a little bit (only) of what you are trying. You are trying something which seems not necessary. Don't try to create buttons out of your code until you are more experienced. Just create the buttons needed first and make them visible or invisble. If you have dynamic data, then choose adding items to a list and not to create new buttons dynamically. (How much buttons do you expect on your window? You have to position them..) I haven't yet seen code which wants to create a button dynamically. To me it sounds that you have misunderstood something how a user interface should work.

Answer (score 0):

I moved this to another answer because I fear this misleads beginners. Normally you don't have to do the following as a beginner, because it is recommended to start with a new WPF project where all is prepared. But if you know more, you can add WPF stuff manually to a project. As:

Just copy the rest of your code to this new project.

If you want to stay in another already created (but not for WPF) project, you have to prepare it manually for that, which is possibly, if you have learned what to do, but not before.

For example, 
 First, adding project **references** to the following assemblies:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

Second: Adding the correct using statements, e.g.

```
using System.Windows;
```